# find the missing dependencies in order to run my application

Tags: c#

My application cannot run on other computer without visual studio and I don't know what I need to install.
I am using pcapdotnet DLL's version 10 so I have .net 4 on my system and after I try to open my exe file new error windows jump:

> myAplication has stopped working

In my develop machine I checked in add or remove programs and saw .net 4.5 so I try to install it to but still not working.
There is a way to check what is my problem ?

**My solution created with VS2012 and i saw on my develop machine .net framework 4.5 multi-targeting pack installed, maybe this what i missing ?**

Comment: What does the system's event log say?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to just check what you reference and make sure you deploy those dependencies also.

Another way to troubleshoot this is by checking the Fusion log with [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) and see what dlls are searched for and are not found.

And a third and "quick and dirty" way would be to create a MSI setup project in your solution and use the built in functionality that automatically checks the necessary dependencies and adds them to the package that will become the setup kit and there you can see what you might have missed.

---

EDIT: One other way would be to remote debug your application, for this you need 2 "tricks":

- Remote debugging - [How to: Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx)
- Automatically attach the debugger to your process when it starts - [How to: Launch the Debugger Automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx)

This way you can see in visual studio what the problem is in more detail.

Comment: i saw in the error windows file cannot find, in my application i am use exe file that exist inside folder inside my solution and from my code i am call this exe file this way: System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + my exe file maybe this is my problem ?

Comment: all my DLL's exist in the folder, maybe is it something else ?

Comment: and do you deploy that .exe that you call also? Plus keep in mind that if your intent was to call an .exe that is in the same folder as your app, you don't need to add the ....StartupPath prefix, and by default the application will search for it in the current folder.

Comment: yes, all this folder with the exe file exist, what about .net framework 4.5 multi-targeting pack ?

Comment: and the exe file is not the problem because the application use this file only after i add all my files etc..it's something else

Comment: Try one of the methods i detailed in the answer to get a closer look at what's wrong. Either remote debug, or try the Fuslogvw.exe or if you're uncertain about the multi-targeting pack, and you don't really need .net 4.5 switch to .net 4 client profile for instance and see if your solution still builds and try it like that.

Comment: what is Remote debugging and how can i attach the debugger ?

Comment: i will add to my answer in a few minutes